# Bootstrapped mean always almost identical to sample mean?

Tags: sampling, mean, bootstrap, resampling

I'm running a simple bootstrapping experiment with the following code

```py
def Bootstrap(originalData, nTimes):
  
  originalSampleSize = len(originalData)
  bootstrappedMeans = []

  for i in range(nTimes):
    bootstrapped_dataset = np.random.choice(originalData, size=originalSampleSize)
    bootstrapped_single_mean = np.mean(bootstrapped_dataset)
    bootstrappedMeans.append(bootstrapped_single_mean)
  
  return bootstrappedMeans
```

the thing is whenever I run it with nTimes=10000 (the rule of thumb) the mean of the bootstrapped experiments is almost identical to the mean from the original sample

```py
random_data = [random.randrange(18,100) for i in range(30)]
bootstrapped_experiments = Bootstrap(random_data,10000)
```

*random_data* mean: 33.666
*bootstrapped_experiments* mean: 33.65695

I know this is random data, but if it were a real experiment with a sample that takes those values, what's the point of bootstrapping if I'm getting the same mean of the original sample that has **only 30 data points** when I'm trying to estimate the **population mean**. Is my code wrong or am I missing something conceptually?

Comment: What is the variance of `bootstrappedMeans`, and how does it compare to the variance of your original data?

Comment: Apart from self-instruction and testing software, there's no point to bootstrapping an arithmetic mean, because it's easy to compute the result analytically (and yes, the mean of the bootstrap equals the mean of the sample).  One bootstraps properties that are difficult to analyze: that's its point.